# Static public IP V.S. static private IP for Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, iis, dns, windows-server-2012-r2, network-interface

I want to host a [test.addbba.com](http://test.addbba.com) by my virtual machine & Windows Server 2012 R2 & Microsoft Azure; and I want the page to be open to the Internet.

At the moment, the website works. The setting is as follows:

1) In GoDaddy of `www.addbba.com`, the name servers are set with `NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM`, `NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM`, `NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM`.

2) In DigitalOcean of `addbba.com`, I have a `A record` with `test` and `52.174.163.38`.

3) In Windows Server, one item in IIS, no item in DNS Server:

[image]

4) In Microsoft Azure, the setting is:

[image]

However, I realise that every time the Virtual Machine is shut down and restarts, this `Public IP address (52.174.163.38)` changes. So I think I need to set a static IP address.

But I don't know whether I need a [static public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal/) or a [static private IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-pportal/).

It seems that I need a static private IP as the 2nd link. But where did the author got the address `192.168.1.*`?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/

Comment: I have seen this page, but it is hard to understand... That's why I try to ask a precise question and look for a precise solution...

Comment: If you want the page to be open to Internet, you clearly want a Public static IP address

Comment: Indeed, it is a **Public** static IP address. I followed [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal/) and created another virtual machine. What was special is `In the Settings blade, click Public IP address, then in the Create public IP address blade, under Assignment, click Static as shown below. And then click OK.`